import many header files from project into lldb
I would like to know if there is an option to import many header files (C++ headers) into lldb. My goal is to be able to parse addresses as structs/objects, for example:
p *(some_struct *)<some_address
but LLDB doesn't recognize some_struct, obviously, because it doesn't contain the symbols.
I read about clang's modules, but I'm not sure I will be able to import so many header files into the definition of a custom module. The header files are spread across many folder.
Thanks!

You can #include headers in the prefix file that you set in the setting:
  target.expr-prefix -- Path to a file containing expressions to be prepended to all expressions.

That works for simple headers, but note there's no way to pass -I flags to this process, so if there are interdependencies among the headers that may not work.  That's the advantage of clang modules, they are self-contained.

Remember that you can also define structures in the expression parser to use for casting values.  Just do expr struct $MyStruct { int a; int b; char *c;} then you can cast to $MyStruct * in subsequent expressions.  The bit that tells lldb this is a "persistent expression definition" is putting a $ on the front of the name.  Making up a handful of these for the structures you really need may be another way to make available the types you are missing.

thanks! this will work for a simple project, but I'm working on a very large scale project and it contains many headers, in different directories.
